# Vuex store changes not reactive in components

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuex, store

I have a basic store for inserting and deleting from an array

```js
state: {
    assessmentTypes : []
  },
  mutations: {
    setAssessmentTypes(state, assessmentTypes) {
      assessmentTypes.forEach(assessmentType => {
          state.assessmentTypes.push(assessmentType);
      });
    },
    removeAssessmentType ( state, assessmentTypeId ) {
        let assessmentTypeIndex = state.assessmentTypes.map(assessmentType => assessmentType.id).indexOf(assessmentTypeId);
        state.assessmentTypes.splice(assessmentTypeIndex, 1)
    }
  }
```

I get the state assessmentTypes in computed property in one of my components.

```
computed:{
assessmentTypes : {
    get () {
      return this.$store.state.assessmentTypes;
    }
}
```

The problem is I am looping the array in dom for listing a div, but the computed property is not reactive. When I delete or insert a new object into/from the array (through actions), the dom is not rerendering.

Object structure

```
{
      "id": "T7pLDdjmFWAqGiuqB",
      "name": "bbb",
      "code": "BBB",
      "properties": {
          combinationOfAssessments: false,
          staffCanCreateInstance: false
      },
      "identifyingContext": {
          "semId": "2",
          "batchId": "54",
          "staffId": "155",
          "subjectId": "966",
          "subbatchId": "391"
      },
      "permissions": {
          "hod": "1",
          "staff": "1"
      },
      "isActive": "1",
      "createdBy": null,
      "createdUserName": null,
      "createdByUserType": null,
      "createdDate": null,
      "updatedDate": null,
      "updatedBy": null,
      "updatedUserName": null,
      "updatedByUserType": null,
      "propertiesValue": null
  }
```

Comment: Would you add your object structure?

Comment: Are you using namespaced modules in your store?

Comment: Try to debug through Vue developer tool

Comment: @dr_barto no.i am not using namespaced modules

Comment: @K.K I debugged using Vue dev tool.The computed value changes only after refreshing the devtool

Comment: @BeHappy I have added the object in my question

Comment: computed:{
 assessmentTypes() {
      return this.$store.state.assessmentTypes;
    }
} try this way in your computed

Comment: It would be great if create codesandbox. It helps to find solution

Comment: @GermanoBussNiehues I tried that too.But it still is not reactive